# Where setting up the Product ID version, corporation and other application Information in a C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

Anyone could explain me how setting up, in Visual Studio 2013 the application informations thaht you can see when you right-clic on the exe file, and go in the "details" ?

The product id version, the corporation,etc....

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Nixeus

Comment: It depends on whether you are using the 'Express' version of Visual Studio, or a paid version. In the paid versions you use the resource editor to type in the strings you want displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In the solution explorer right click on your project and select Add->Resource.
Select Version.
Fill out the version detail using the resource editor (double click on the resource file).
That's it.